# Getting to Kotor from Podgorica Airport

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, montenegro, podgorica, tgd

A traveller from Vienna wants to meet up with her friends in Kotor, Montenegro.  Because there were no good flights to the nearby Tivat Airport, she instead booked a flight to Podgorica Airport, arriving on 6 March at 14:30.  What are the best ways of getting from Podgorica Airport to Kotor?  Here are the two options she is considering so far:

- **Renting a car in Podgorica Airport.** While she has a driving licence, she has never driven regularly, and not at all in the last five years. So she is unsure about driving alone in a foreign country with an unfamiliar car.  What is the route like between Podgorica Airport and Kotor?  Will this be a safe and easy trip for an unskilled driver, or do the road conditions or traffic make this unsuitable?
- **Train to Podgorica, then bus to Kotor.**  There's a train from the Aerodrom station near Podgorica Airport to Podgorica, and thence a bus to Kotor.  Is this connection safe and reliable?  If so, is it advisable to buy tickets in advance or is it OK to get them on the day from the driver/station?

Are there any other options worth considering?  She has hand luggage only and no mobility problems, so walking to change connections (say, a kilometre or so) is no problem, provided the path is simple and suitable for a wheeled bag.

Answer (score 5):

There's no public bus from Podgorica airport, so the train is the only public transport option.

There's no desk at the Aerodrom station, so you get the ticket on the train, though the conductor likely won't get to you by the time you reach Podgorica, meaning you could get a free ride.

As for local roads and driving habits, definitely not recommended for an inexperienced driver.

Comment: Could you clarify your last comment about local roads and driving habits? What in particular is bad about them? Are the roads in poor condition or poorly signposted? Is the traffic heavy or the other drivers erratic?

Comment: @Psychonaut Mountainous and curvy, while many drive recklessly, incl. but not limited to driving past others in curves